# Redux - Adding element to array nested in an object inside an array

Tags: arrays, redux, react-redux

Can't figure out how to properly insert an element into an array, that's inside an object, that's inside an array. Here's an example of my default data for structure:

```
const defaultState = {
  myinbox: [
    {
      owner: 'John Lennon',
      owner_id: 1,
      read: true,
      messages: [
        {
          _id: 1,
          text: 'When will you be home?',
          createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 10, 11, 11, 20, 0)),
          user: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 'John Lennon'
          }
        }
 ...
```

I want to add another message when an inbound message comes in. This is what the snippet from my reducer looks like:

```
const inboxReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_INBOUND_MESSAGE':
      return {
        ...state,
        myinbox: [
          state.myinbox[action.payload.index]: {
            ...state.myinbox[action.payload.index],
            messages: [
              ...state.myinbox[action.payload.index].messages,
              action.payload.msg
            ]
          }
          ...state.myinbox,
        ]
      }
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

The index of the parent "owner" is passed as the index inside the payload, and the new message is msg in the payload.

I can't figure out how to write this reducer without mutating the original state.

Answer (score 2):

You're mutating the original state when you set `myinbox` using `state.myinbox[action.payload.index]:`.

Looks like you're trying to set the state for the index using [computed property keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). The syntax for that would be:

```
    myinbox: [
      [action.payload.index]: {
        ...state.myinbox[action.payload.index],
        messages: [
          ...state.myinbox[action.payload.index].messages,
          action.payload.msg
        ]
      }
      ...state.myinbox,
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer)

```
  const { index, msg } = action.payload;
  return produce(state, (draftState) => {
    draftState.myinbox[index].messages.push(msg);
  });
```